Relation assessment of different variables on small species occurance data
I have 21 points for a species location (13 for presence and 8 for absence) within an area. Also, I have collected (road (distance from spp will be calculated), water bodies (distance from spp will be calculated), pipelines (distance from spp will be calculated), soil type, land cover) other GIS layers (both categorical and continuous).
Now I want to see the relationship of these variables with the species occurrence data. I read somewhere that logistic regression can be used to assess the relationship between the dependent variables as categorical. However, considering the small number of data points (21) is it something that I should be doing? Or should I consider a correlation test that will investigate the influence of the gis layers on the species' occurrence?

Most correlation tests are equivalent to testing the outputs of a regression model. A regression model is a correlation test. There's a growing movement in statistics to stop using named "tests" (for example, people saying "we used Fisher's Exact Test") and to encourage people to use regression models that better represent the data and make them think about what they are trying to get from the data.
Whether you put 21 data points into a logistic regression or into some canned test makes no difference - you don't get any more information for free. What will happen with small data points is that the uncertainty on your fitted parameters will be large unless you have a very strong effect, for example if all the presence points are closer to the roads than all the absence points.
So my advice would be fit the logistic regression model, but be aware of all the issues around regression modelling (which apply to small data and big data alike).
